# Javascript files loaded but calls not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will be using the same header on two sites, one is already up and running with no issues, the second I can't seem to get my Javascript to work despite it being the exact same code as on the site that does work?

Here is the scripts and the Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/tinynav.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    pagination  : "#sliderpagi",
    scroll : {
            duration        : 1000,                         
            pauseOnHover    : true
        }                   
    });
    $('.mobilemenu').tinyNav();
});
</script>
```

I have checked all the files are where they should be to rule that out or before it is suggested.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Been fighting with it the best part of the day. I'd love to get it working but also understand why the same code works on a different site?

Also to note - I have the same HTML for the Carousel and tinynav as i do on the working site.

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carouFredSel is not a function
(anonymous function) @ index2.html:23
x.Callbacks.c @ jquery.min.js:4
x.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:4
x.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:4
q @ jquery.min.js:4 

Searching Google lead me to believe this is relatively normal and should still work regardless of the error.

Comment: is file name ```carouFredSel``` correct? and file exist?

Comment: yes and yes. The site for it is: http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel

Comment: Your `carouFredSel` code seems to work with no issues. [(Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/pmn80k6j/)

Comment: It's definitely because of  ```carouFredSel``` not being loaded, make sure that you are not adding jquery script after in elsewhere

Comment: what's on index2.html:23 ?

Comment: Stryner Correct, the same code works on my other site.
Grievoushead it doesn't seem to be loading correctly as it has no effect, the same with tinynav.
@GrafiCode Studio line 23 is: $('#carousel').carouFredSel({